# PHP class inheritance depth

Tags: php, eclipse, class-design

I'm trying to work out exactly how deep inheritance goes.

For example if I start with class A

Class B extends class A
Class C extends class B
Class D extends class C
Class E extends class D
Class F extends class E
Class G extends class F

most of the lower levels are abstract classes with methods filled with code and abstract methods. its a rather large and complex structure. (doing my head in)

Will Class G still be able to access Class A methods and parameters, as well as still have access to the abstract methods from Class A ?

I'm asking because I have been having trouble with eclipse not adding the lower class methods into the auto complete. I would like to know if there is actually a limit to this or whether it's just eclipse reaching its maximum for code completion.

I'm far from a stage where I can test this with what I have done and don't want to find when I'm done that methods defined lower in the order are not accessible.

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like a problem with your editor. For example, see the following quick-and-dirty demonstration:

```
php > class a { function foo() { echo "A::foo()\n"; } }
php > $letters = range('a', 'z');
php > for ($i = 0; $i < 25; $i++) { eval("class {$letters[$i+1]} extends {$letters[$i]} {}"); }
php > $z = new z;
php > $z->foo();
A::foo()
```

PHP doesn't impose any kind of restriction like this on you.

Answer (score 2):

Using a [canonical test](http://ideone.com/LGrsc) like this:

```
<?php
abstract class A {
    abstract function getValue();
}
abstract class B extends A{ }
abstract class C extends B{ }
abstract class D extends C{ }
abstract class E extends D{ }
abstract class F extends E{ }
class G extends F{

}
?>
```

one would expect a fatal error in that `G` does not in fact implement the abstract method defined in `A`.  As you can see from the link above, this is in fact the case.

Thus, while this is a deep inheritance, it is beneath whatever limit (if any) PHP has.  Rather, you're likely running into an indexer issue in the PDT.

Comment: Thanks a lot. i suspected this was the issue but i just wasnt sure. i was also keen to find out if there is an actual limit to this structure.

Comment: I don't think there is an explicit limit for 'inheritance levels'. It's not like you need to put all parent classes on some stack that might overflow or something. If anything, the necessity to load all parent classes will mean that the memory available for the script is the actual limit.

Answer (score -1):

The following php:

```
class A
{
    public function FooA()
    {
        echo "A!!";
    }
}

class B extends A
{
    public function FooB()
    {
        echo "B!!";
    }
}

class C extends B
{
    public function FooC()
    {
        parent::FooB();
        parent::FooA();
    }
}

$test = new C();
$test->FooC();
```

prints:

`B!!A!!`

I tested this at a depth of 50 and it still functioned just fine, so you definitely can, sounds like your editor plug-in only looks so deep in the inheritance tree