# PHP: How far can one extend classes?

Tags: php, class, oop, extends

This may be a bit of a noob question, and it has probably been asked before (and if so, where?).

I am wondering how "far" one can extend classes in PHP.

For example:

`class baz`

`class bar extends baz`

`class foo extends bar`

`class foobar extends foo`

And maybe this is not the right way of going about this.

If this is explained anywhere (yes, I did google the question and also read different docs on [php.net](http://php.net) on OOP and classes) do tell.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: They say there is no limit - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4811123/php-class-inheritance-depth